# Что не так с количством дней?

Tags: javascript

Делаю каскадный dropdown list с параметрами год, месяц, день.

Есть функция, которая выдает количество дней в месяце

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
        return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что когда я передаю аргументы daysInMonth(0, 2020), и  daysInMonth(1, 2020) - в обоих случаях получается январь

В итоге получается, что когда я выбираю 2020 год, Февраль, у меня 31 день )

Прототип здесь: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/hrekj8na/75/)

[image: Скрин]

Полагаю, что куда-то нужно добавить +1, а вот куда, не пойму

Comment: Ну так ферваль это 2, всё правильно. У вас в марте получилось 29 дней, потому что март это вообще-то 3, а не 2

Comment: Месяцы (как и дни) нумеруются с 1, а не с 0...

Comment: daysInMonth(0, 2020) - это декабрь 2019. Именно в вашем случае, если передать 1 - это будет первый месяц в году.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов месяцы то как раз нумеруются с нуля.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ок, значит некорректно перенес свои представления с другого языка.  Хотя тогда непонятен Ваш комментарий про декабрь 2019....

Comment: Месяцы нумеруются с нуля, дни с единицы. Такой вот прикол…

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values

Comment: В `daysInMonth(0, 2020)` у вас получается декабрь 2019 в котором по счастливому совпадению тоже 31 день

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов если передать 0 в третий параметр конструктора Date (который отвечает за день месяца), то будет создана дата с минус одним днем, т.к. отсчет дней начинается с 1. Соответственно, если передать -1 в третий параметр, то создается дата с минус двумя днями.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ясно, спасибо.

Comment: Я тут нашел решение. Вот здесь прототип: https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/hrekj8na/109/

Comment: Если нашли решение - можете написать ответ.